# Delphi - How to create Excel PivotChart

Tags: excel, delphi, pivot-chart

I am trying to automate a series of PivotCharts within Excel.  I am using Delphi Rio and Excel 2019.  I have an XLSX file, with one sheet, called 'Sheet1'.  I have enabled record macro within Excel, and recorded the VBA code.  I have ported it to Delphi.  Everything compiles, and I get an AV when I go to add my row fields (which becomes Axis fields in the PivotChart).  In Excel, to record the macro, I select my sheet with my data, go to Insert/Pivot Chart, checking 'Add Data to Data Model', and then build a simple PivotChart.

The VBA code is

```
Cells.Select
    Workbooks("TestFile.xlsx").Connections.Add2 "WorksheetConnection_Sheet1!$A:$CU" _
        , "", "WORKSHEET;S:\Temp\[TestFile.xlsx]Sheet1", "Sheet1!$A:$CU", 7, True, _
        False
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlExternal, SourceData:= _
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections("WorksheetConnection_Sheet1!$A:$CU"), Version:=7). _
        CreatePivotChart(ChartDestination:="Sheet3").Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.ChartStyle = 201
    With ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.CubeFields("[Range].[Fiscal Quarter]")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.CubeFields("[Range].[Territory Name]")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.CubeFields.GetMeasure "[Range].[Pipeline]", _
        xlSum, "Sum of Pipeline"
    ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.AddDataField ActiveChart.PivotLayout. _
        PivotTable.CubeFields("[Measures].[Sum of Pipeline]"), "Sum of Pipeline"
```

The problem I run into (when running my Delphi compiled executable' is when adding the 'Fiscal Quarter' rowfield. It APPEARS that CubeFields is not defined, although I get 'data inaccessible' when I mouse over it.  So my first question, in Delphi, is CubeFields created automatically?

My Delphi code is

```
    procedure BuildPivotChart;
    var
    
     myChart: _Chart;
     myChartShape: Shape;
     myPivotCache: PivotCache;
     
     SourceSheet, DestSheet: _Worksheet;
     myConnection: WorkbookConnection;
     ConnName, ConnString, ConnCommand: String;
     
    begin
    
      // Create the connection since we are adding to DataModel
      ConnName := 'WorksheetConnection_Sheet1!$A:$CU';
      ConnString := 'WORKSHEET;S:\Temp\[TestFile.xlsx]Sheet1';
      ConnCommand := 'Sheet1!$A:$CU';
      myConnection := oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Add2(ConnName, '', ConnString, ConnCommand, 7, True, False);
    
    
       // Create a new Sheet, and get a handle to it...
       oExcel.Worksheets.Add(EmptyParam, EmptyParam,1, xlWorksheet, LCID );
    
      // Get a handle to the new sheet and set the Sheet Name
      DestSheet := oExcel.ActiveSheet as _Worksheet;
      DestSheet.Name := 'Graphs';
    
      // Create a Pivot Cache, with a Chart object
       myPivotCache := oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlExternal, myConnection, 7);
       myChartShape := myPivotCache.CreatePivotChart(DestSheet, xlColumnClustered, 10, 10, 300, 300);
       myChartShape.Select(EmptyParam);
       myChart := oExcel.ActiveChart;
       myChart.ChartStyle := 201; 
    
       if oExcel.ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotCache.IsConnected = True then
       ShowMessage('Connected');
      
    
       // Now add Row Fields
       // ALL THREE OF THE BELOW LINES gives AV
       oExcel.ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.CubeFields.AddSet('[Range].[Fiscal Quarter]', 'MyName').Orientation := xlRowField;
       oExcel.ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.CubeFields['[Range].[Fiscal Quarter]'].Orientation := xlRowField;
       
       // Thinking that the CUBE is not defined... check to see cube fields count..
        ShowMessage(IntToStr(oExcel.ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.CubeFields.Count));

...
```

When I step through my Delphi code, on the 'myPivotCache.CreatePivotChart' line, I see the chart object show up in Excel, and I see my columns listed in the Pivot selected on the right side of Excel.  I have a suspicion that something is wrong with CubeFields, but I can't prove it, or I don't know how to fix it... I DO get my 'Connected' popup.

Any help or ideas appreciated.

Comment: can you break and inspect the PivotTable at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when using EXCEL_TLB units.

It can be solved by changing to OLE development.

Comment: That did it.  EXCEL_TLB just would not allow it...  Any idea how to fix? (I did get OLE development to work).

Answer (score 0):

Use add unit "Excel2010" to "Uses" after interface, as:
interface
uses Excel2010